# Can plants be grown using lights in the home?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, photosynthesis

Plants need sunlight to grow, mainly the blue and red wavelength of the sunlight . The lights used in homes are also white light, it will also have red and blue wavelength of light.

So , can they be grown in such lights perfectly?

Comment: Yes, though you may need special full-spectrum lights.  Ask any operator of a marijuana grow house :-)

Comment: Sunlight is about 60,000 lumens per square meter . A 100 watt incandescent bulb produces only about 1,600 lumens.

Comment: @Jim Young: People still use incandescents?

Comment: @jamesqf. No. But most of us have an awareness of the brightness of a 100 watt bulb. Point is how dim interior lighting is compared to outdoors. The OPs logic is okay, but off by a few orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what kind of light you are using. I recently did an experiment on this for my school's science fair and I found that you can use LED lights to grow plants. Nowadays you can actually buy LED lights called "Grow Lights" to grow your plant and the only difference is that Now the current LED lights that are used include four LED lights into groups where each light can produce the correct wavelength that will allow for increased production of growth. For beneficial growth of the cannabis plant for example  you want to use your LED lights directed at 439nm, 469nm, 642nm and 667nm. Link http://easy420grow.com/what-is-the-difference-between-hid-grow-lights-and-led-grow-lamps

Answer (score 2):

Typically, regular incandescent bulbs like the ones you'd use in your house omit orange and yellow light. These wavelengths of light are used in photosynthesis but foliage growth relies more on blue wavelengths of light. Therefore regular lights aren't ideal for the growth of plants. Incandescent bulbs also generate a fair amount of heat which can damage plants when the bulbs are placed too close. Usually supplemental lighting is needed to grow plants with artificial life (eg. fluorescent, grow lights etc).

However, if there is a window in the room, plants generally do well even with just diffused light.